# selecting a row using MIN or ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle table which is similar to the one below which stores people's lastname firstname and age. If last name is same people belong to same family.

```
   LastName   FirstName  Age
   ===========================
1   miller     charls     20
2   miller     john       30
3   anderson   peter      45
4   Bates      andy       50
5   anderson   gary       60
6   williams   mark       15
```

I need to write a oracle sql query to 
select youngest person from each family. output shd select rows 1,3,4 and 6

How do I do this ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: What if it's a tie?  Also, how are you identifying families?

Comment: select lname, MIN(age) as age from peopletable.  Would this work ? Is this the efficient way ?

Comment: @irappa it will work but it will not display `firstname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DENSE_RANK()` is a ranking function which generates sequential number and for ties the number generated is the same. I prefer to use `DENSE_RANK()` here considering that a family can have twins, etc.

```
SELECT  Lastname, FirstName, Age
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  Lastname, FirstName, Age,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LastName ORDER BY Age) rn
            FROM    tableName
        ) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd69f/3)

Comment: If am sure there will be no twins (no tie), can I get rid of DENSE_RANK ? that might make the query faster ?

Comment: change it to `ROW_NUMBER()`. or see Nicholas' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, a bit *shorter*:

```
select lastname
     , max(firstname) keep(dense_rank first order by age) as first_name
     , max(age)       keep(dense_rank first order by age) as age
  from you_table_name
 group by lastname
 order by lastname
```

Result:

```
LASTNAME   FIRST_NAME        AGE
--------   ---------- ----------
Bates      andy               50 
anderson   peter              45 
miller     charls             20 
williams   mark               15
```

And [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05eda/2)

Answer (score 0):

With **Standard SQL** I would do as this...

```
select *
from   family f1
where (
  select  count(*) 
  from family f2
  where 
    f2.lastname = f1.lastname 
    and 
    f2.age <= f1.age) <= 1
order by lastname;
```

This SQL gives you possibilities to pick x youngest/oldest in a family. Just modify the f2.age <= f1.age to e.g. f2.age >= f1.age, and the <= 1 to e.g. <=10 (to get top 10 youngest/oldest in a family).

[**<kbd>SQLfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/26bc8/1)